# Valgrind doesn't like my pop() function for a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working on a terminal snake game in c using ncurses, and I have the snake set up as a doubly linked list using the following code:

```c
typedef struct {
    int y; 
    int x;
} coordinates;

bool coordsequal(coordinates c1, coordinates c2);

typedef struct {
    coordinates coords;
    char attire;
} object;

typedef object part;

/* Snake: Doubly Linked list of Parts */
typedef struct dllsnake {
    part part;
    struct dllsnake *prev;
    struct dllsnake *next;
} snake;
```

With this, I defined a function that pops the last element off of the snake linked list:

```c
snake *pop(snake *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        // List is empty, nothing to pop
        return NULL;
    }

    snake *ptr; // line 84
    for (ptr = head; ptr->next != NULL; ptr = ptr->next); // line 85

    snake *new_tail = ptr->prev; // line 87
    new_tail->next = NULL;
    free(ptr);

    return new_tail;
}
```

This function works as intended in the snake game, deleting the snake's tail when prompted to. However, when I run my snake game with valgrind, valgrind has many complaints about this function, including:

- Invalid read of size 8 at lines 84, 85, and 87
- Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc() at line 87
- Addresses 0x4b52d10, 0x4b52d20, and 0x4b52d28 are 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd, line 87

What's more, when the snake game is run with valgrind, the pop() function stops working entirely.

I don't know what to do with these messages! For the first one, it isn't apparent how I'm reading any memory that I'm not supposed to be reading. For the second, why would it be pointing at line 87 if the free statement is two lines later? And I don't know what the last point is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please copy-paste the full and complete Valgrind output into the question. And if possible please try to create a [mre] as well.

Comment: And a couple of tips for future linked lists: Create separate structures for the nodes and the list itself. Then it's easier for the second tip: Keep a pointer to the tail of the list.

Comment: you can't get that error for line 84, it doesn't read anything. So I don't think you have the line numbers correct.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the last tail to NULL?

Comment: OT: "**Ouroboros**" It's a DLL (double linked list) in which each segment contains the necessary attributes of that segment of the snake. Try coding it with the tail (the 'last' node) _connected_ to the head (the all-important 'first' node.) No need to traverse the full length to get to the tail...

Comment: If you're removing an item from a list and returning it, why are you calling `free()` at all?

Comment: It's possible your linked list was corrupted by other parts of your code and pop() is just revealing the consequences. Try writing a function to print the linked list, and run it before `pop` to see the state of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `pop()` will segfault on `new_tail->next` if `head->prev==NULL` when the list contains 1 node.
2. `pop()` usually transfer ownership to caller which frees the node when done.  This means `pop()` should not free it.
3. If you want to be able to free the head node then you need to (preferred) pass in `snake **head` so you can update it, return the new head (probably not suitable here as you want return the last ) or have caller keep track.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int y;
    int x;
} coordinates;

bool coordsequal(coordinates c1, coordinates c2);

typedef struct {
    coordinates coords;
    char attire;
} object;

typedef object part;

/* Snake: Doubly Linked list of Parts */
typedef struct dllsnake {
    part part;
    struct dllsnake *prev;
    struct dllsnake *next;
} snake;

snake *create(snake *prev) {
    snake *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if(!n) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->prev = prev;
    if(prev) prev->next = n;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

snake *pop(snake **head) {
    if (!head || !*head) return NULL;
    snake *ptr;
    for (ptr = *head; ptr->next != NULL; ptr = ptr->next);
    if(ptr->prev)
        ptr->prev->next = NULL;
    else
        *head = NULL;
    ptr->prev= NULL;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    return ptr;
}

void print(const char *prefix, snake *head) {
    printf("%s:\n", prefix);
    for(; head; head=head->next)
        printf("\tnode=%p prev=%p next=%p\n", (void *) head, (void *) head->prev, (void *) head->next);
}
int main(void) {
    snake *head = create(NULL);
    create(head);
    print("head with two nodes", head);

    snake *node = pop(&head);
    print("head after first pop", head);
    print("node first pop", node);
    free(node);

    snake *node2 = pop(&head);
    print("head after 2nd pop", head);
    print("node after 2nd pop", node2);
    free(node2);
}
```

and example run:

```
head with two nodes:
        node=0x557bc52bd2a0 prev=(nil) next=0x557bc52bd2d0
        node=0x557bc52bd2d0 prev=0x557bc52bd2a0 next=(nil)
head after first pop:
        node=0x557bc52bd2a0 prev=(nil) next=(nil)
node first pop:
        node=0x557bc52bd2d0 prev=(nil) next=(nil)
head after 2nd pop:
node after 2nd pop:
        node=0x557bc52bd2a0 prev=(nil) next=(nil)
```

and valgrind seems to be happy:

```
==98314== HEAP SUMMARY:
==98314==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==98314==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,088 bytes allocated
==98314== 
==98314== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

If you want to do the free within `pop()` you could do this:

```
int pop(snake **head, part *result) {
    if (!head || !*head || !result) return 1;
    snake *ptr;
    for (ptr = *head; ptr->next != NULL; ptr = ptr->next);
    if(ptr->prev)
        ptr->prev->next = NULL;
    else
        *head = NULL;
    *result = ptr->part;
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}

// ...

int main(void) {

   // ...

    part part;
    if(pop(&head, &part)) {
        // handle underflow
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Excuse me for my late response. Your solution does work, although I don't understand your second point: what do you mean by `pop()` "transferring owner to caller?" And do you mean that calling `free()` inside of a function is a bad practice in general? I have this function for freeing the snake which has given me no issues:
`void freesnake(snake *head) {
 if (head == NULL) 
  return;
 freesnake(head->next);
 free(head);
}`
(sorry for the bad formatting)

Comment: When you heap allocate memory someone needs to take on the liability of freeing that `ptr` again, right?  I referred to that party as the owner.  In the above I explained the case where the caller takes on that liability.  The other valid option is the stack so we have to call `free(ptr)` after return, this means, you need to make a copy of the node, for example, `snake tmp = *ptr; free(ptr); return tmp;` (by we return an object not a pointer).

Comment: Both are valid design choices.  Transferring the ownership might be faster especially if it's a large object as we don't have to copy it.  If you return a copy, then the stack can take care of both `malloc` and `free` and that symmetry helps to avoid memory leaks. As the caller gets a copy, if they need the object to outlive the local scope, then caller needs to heap allocate memory `snake *tmp = malloc(*tmp); tmp = pop(...)`.  Now the *both* caller and the stack does malloc and free.

Comment: The sample code is perfectly fine (as stack still owns that memory).  Prefer an iterative solution as C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization so a recursive algorithm may use O(n) stack space.

Comment: For curiosity's sake, how would you rewrite this function while keeping `free` inside of the `pop` function?

Comment: Updated answer with an implementation.  Please ask a new question next time.

Comment: Btw, you may not want use the same identifier for the typedef and variable as they share the same name space.  `part part` also means that the identifier `part` in that scope now refers to the variable (and hides the type) so `part part2` would a syntax error.  `sizeof(part); part *part; sizeof(part);` will return two different values (of type and variable).